# C# - Reading text file, comparing the dictionary data and finding frequency of each

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a text file called **data.txt** which contains data of replaced text.

Contents of **data.txt**:

> Line 1: System1 ->        MachineA
>
> Line 2: System2 ->        MachineB
>
> Line 3: System3 ->        MachineC
>
> Line 4: System4 ->        MachineD
>
> Line 4: System6 ->        MachineF
>
> Line 5: System5 ->        MachineE
>
> Line 6: System6 ->        MachineF
>
> Line 7: System7 ->        MachineG
>
> Line 8: System2 ->        MachineB
>
> Line 8: System8 ->        MachineH

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] arrayofLine = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");

            Dictionary<string, string> Replaced = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<int, string> Frequency = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Replaced.Add("System1", "MachineA");
            Replaced.Add("System2", "MachineB");
            Replaced.Add("System3", "MachineC");
            Replaced.Add("System4", "MachineD");
            Replaced.Add("System5", "MachineE");
            Replaced.Add("System6", "MachineF");
            Replaced.Add("System7", "MachineG");
            Replaced.Add("System8", "MachineH");
            int countr = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayofLine.Length;i++ )
            {
                foreach(var replacement in Replaced.Keys)
                {
                    if (arrayofLine[i].Contains(replacement))
                    {
                        countr++;
                         //if (Frequency.ContainsKey(countr))
                        //{
                        //    Frequency[countr] = Frequency[countr] + "|" + replacement;
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    Frequency.Add(countr, replacement);
                        //}
                        Frequency.Add(countr, Convert.ToString(replacement));
                    }
                }

            }


            StringBuilder sbFreq = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(var freq in Frequency)
            {
                sbFreq.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} has been replaced with {1} {2} time(s) ", freq.Value, Replaced[freq.Value], freq.Key));
            }

            Console.Write(sbFreq);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The Dictionary **Replaced**: Replaced.Keys contains the original data (System1, System2.... SystemN)and Replaced.Values contains the replaced data (MachineA, MachineB.... MachineN)

**Output of the code:**

```
System1 has been replaced with MachineA 1 time(s)

System2 has been replaced with MachineB 2 time(s)

System3 has been replaced with MachineC 3 time(s)

System4 has been replaced with MachineD 4 time(s)

System6 has been replaced with MachineF 5 time(s)

System5 has been replaced with MachineE 6 time(s)

System6 has been replaced with MachineF 7 time(s)

System7 has been replaced with MachineG 8 time(s)

System2 has been replaced with MachineB 9 time(s)

System8 has been replaced with MachineH 10 time(s)
```

It counts for number of lines, I would like to count the frequency or the number of times the original text has been replaced.

**Desired Output:**

```
System1 has been replaced with MachineA 1 time(s)

System2 has been replaced with MachineB 2 time(s)

System3 has been replaced with MachineC 1 time(s)

System4 has been replaced with MachineD 1 time(s)

System6 has been replaced with MachineF 2 time(s)

System5 has been replaced with MachineE 1 time(s)

System7 has been replaced with MachineG 1 time(s)

System8 has been replaced with MachineH 1 time(s)
```

How can the desired output be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just count how many times it occurs?

First get the unique records:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayofLine.Length; i++)
        {
           //Your original logic here
        }

//This is an additional code:
Frequency = Frequency.GroupBy(s => s.Value)
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);  //Get only the distinct records.

StringBuilder sbFreq = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var freq in Frequency)
     {
sbFreq.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} has been replaced with {1} {2} time(s) ",
freq.Value, Replaced[freq.Value], 
arrayofLine.Where(x => x.Contains(freq.Value)).Count())); //Here is the modification part
    }
```

You will receive the desired output:

[image]

Comment: When I Console.WriteLine(sbFreq);

It displays blank console window.

Comment: I didn't modify everything. I just added the GroupBy on your dictionary variable (Frequency = Frequency.GroupBy). And edited the foreach loop. I updated my post so that you can follow. The rest are all your code.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer would be to put the `countr` declaration into the loop and swap the loops (Mukesh's answer forgot to change the location of `countr`)

```
foreach(var replacement in Replaced.Keys)
{
    //countr will only count occurrences PER INDIVIDUAL REPLACEMENT
    int countr = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayofLine.Length;i++ )
    {
         if (arrayofLine[i].Contains(replacement)) countr++;
    }

    Frequency.Add(countr, Convert.ToString(replacement));
}
```

This is the "simplest" solution to your problem. I.e. fixing the issue with minimal code changes.

However, I want to highlight that there is a better way of approaching this, using LINQ. In common cases of iterations, LINQ can simplify the code considerably (mainly by reducing nesting and repetitive code).

Using LINQ, I could refactor your entire snippet into a single line:

```
Frequency = Replaced.ToDictionary(
                            x => x.Key,
                            x => arrayofLine.Count(line => line.Contains(x.Key))
                        );
```

Notice that I am using `Dictionary<string, int> Frequency`, not `Dictionary<int,string>` (your version doesn't make sense, since multiple replacements can have the same amount of occurrences).

**However**, if you are expecting to also execute the actual string replacements in the same iteration, you will need to be more verbose. You can still use LINQ, but you need to iterate manually so you can add the needed replacement logic in every step.

Something like this:

```
foreach(var replacement in Replaced)
{   
    //Count how often it occurs
    Frequency.Add(
                  replacement.Key, 
                  arrayofLine.Count(line => line.Contains(replacement.Key))
              );

    //And also replac the occurrences!
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayofLine.Length;i++ )
    {
         if (arrayofLine[i].Contains(replacement)) 
             arrayofLine[i] = arrayofLine[i].Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
    }

}
```

**There is still one potential bug**:
If a single line can contain the same replacement value several times, maybe you should could the amount of occurrences, rather than the amount of lines which contain at least one occurrence.
But if a replacement value will never occur twice, this is a non-issue.

If this is an issue, I would suggest looking into it and posting a new question if you run into any problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Only swap loop it will work

```
 foreach(var replacement in Replaced.Keys)
     { 
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayofLine.Length;i++ )
                    {

                            if (arrayofLine[i].Contains(replacement))
                            {
                                countr++;
                                 //if (Frequency.ContainsKey(countr))
                                //{
                                //    Frequency[countr] = Frequency[countr] + "|" + replacement;
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                //    Frequency.Add(countr, replacement);
                                //}
                                Frequency.Add(countr, Convert.ToString(replacement));
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: It gives the same output

Answer (score 0):

The code as is, doesn't actually use the dictionaries as dictionaries, but perhaps the initial values are irrelevant and only all `line x: system -> machine` combinations should be parsed?
(in other words: can the file contain systems that are not in the Replacement list?)

One alternative is to use a form of regex to get all combinations:

```
//arrayofLine = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");
var rx = new Regex(@"(?:.*:\s*)(\w+)(?:\s*->\s*)(\w+)");
string sFreq = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, from l in arrayofLine
    let m = rx.Match(l)
    where m.Success
    group l by new {From = m.Groups[1].Value, To = m.Groups[2].Value} into g
    select $"{g.Key.From} has been replaced with {g.Key.To} {g.Count()} time(s)"
);
```

`sFreq` will contain the desired result, based on the example input.
Note this groups on all unique from -> to combinations, but in the sample code each 'from' (system) seems to be set to the same 'to' (machine). If only system has to be checked, the code (grouping) could be simplified